# How to manage Connection Pool Limit when application have many calls?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on mail demo application using C#.net. I got error of because I cross the limit of max connection.
In my case, I need to insert mail one by one to database and also retrieve frequently on the base of timer. 
It may have 5-10 mail account and each account may have thousands of email.
Suggest me way to manage sql connection.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: I use mysql. @un-lucky

Comment: Why not using a ThreadPool with threadLimit.

Comment: I don't have much idea about ThreadPool. Let me see it. Thank you @nomail

Comment: posted an answer. Adjust MaxThreads to your needs.

Comment: It appears u are missing on closing the connections after use. There may be connection leaks. Try using statement around fetch statements. Addtionaly make sure that if data is being fetched for one user, your system does not open another connection for the same user. Use Tasks to manage background work.

Comment: @FaizanKhan I open connection and close in case of insert and delete. I  open connection in case of select and don't close it as select fires frequently. Suggest me if I am doing mistake.

Comment: @NJBhanushali Can u share code regarding select and where/how it is called.

Comment: I can't share but i can tell you flow.


#for insert

1- open connection + transaction. 

2- insert query. 

3- Close connection + Transaction. 


#Select

1- Check for connection. If It's closed, It will open else not. 

2- Select query. 

//doesn't close because Select query fires frequenty.

Comment: @FaizanKhan some times i get this error : Authentication to host '192.168.x.xx' for user 'abc' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed.

Comment: It's not clear without code, and i m not sure how u r resuing single connection for select, if u r using single connection the app pool error cannot occur b.c of only one connection. Anyways its just a guess its difficult to tell without code.

Comment: Regarding reading from stream failed problem, server sometimes closes connection if idle for some time, that may be the reason

Answer (score 0):

You have to do Three things:

1.Include the following elements into your connection string:

```
pooled=true;Max Pool Size=100;
```

2.Open new connection only if the connection state is closed:

```
 If dbCon.ConnectionState<>ConnectionState.Open Then
     dbCon.Open()
 End If
```

3.Avoid opening new connection within the loop. if you are using Loops

Comment: ok. I open connection and close in case of insert and delete. I open connection in case of select and don't close it as select fires frequently. Suggest me if I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Get Nuget Package:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nelibur.Sword

```
ITinyThreadPool threadPool = TinyThreadPool.Create(x =>

    {
        x.MaxThreads = 2;
        x.MultiThreadingCapacity = MultiThreadingCapacity.Global;
    });
```

Then just use this threadPool to do process database inserts. Also this way you don't rely on a database pool.

```
threadPool.AddTask(() => Insert(document))
```